# Cloud code: can I use other files besides main.js?

Tags: parse-platform

Does all my cloud clode have to be in main.js or can I create other logical files and somehow add them into my cloud code?

Comment: You can add other files and use require to reference them in any of the js files.

Answer (score 23):

If you just want to split your Parse.Cloud functions in multiple files, you also can do that and just require the file in your main.js.

So you can have this in your cloud/main.js

```
require('cloud/userFunctions.js')
```

and have all the related functions in your cloud/userFunctions.js

```
Parse.Cloud.define("processUserRequest", function(request, response) {

// do your stuff

});
```

Comment: that really keeps main.js clean!

Comment: Does this work as well for beforeSave and afterSave functions? can this be also stored in separate files?

Answer (score 8):

You can split your code into different files using require.

The example below come from [Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#modules)

If you have some code in cloud/name.js

```
var coolNames = ['Ralph', 'Skippy', 'Chip', 'Ned', 'Scooter'];
exports.isACoolName = function(name) {
return coolNames.indexOf(name) !== -1;
}
```

You can then you it in cloud/main.js

```
var name = require('cloud/name.js');
name.isACoolName('Fred'); // returns false
name.isACoolName('Skippy'); // returns true;
name.coolNames; // undefined.
```

Comment: While following your example, I placed both *.js files in folder 'cloud'. However, I was struggling with error "Error generating response. { Error: Cannot find module 'cloud/name.js'..." for `var name = require('cloud/name.js');`. Changing the path solved it: `var name = require('./name.js');`. Parse Server version 2.8.2.

Comment: Works & keeps things nice n clean